# Inheritance from UIWebView adding my own delegate gives fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None

Tags: ios, uiwebview, delegates, swift

I've been programming in Obj-C for a couple of years and I decided to make my next app in Swift to get the experience and learn some new stuff. Needless to say I'm finding some concepts hard to understand like Optional variables for example.

At the moment I'm trying to inherit from a UIWebView and add my own delegate to my class. Here is the code for my class:

```
@objc protocol WebViewWithGesturesDelegate{    
    @optional func webViewWithGestures(webViewWithGestures: WebViewWithGestures!,         didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!)
}

class WebViewWithGestures: UIWebView, UIWebViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    var errorDelegate : WebViewWithGesturesDelegate?

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
{        
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.delegate = self
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!){
    errorDelegate?.webViewWithGestures!(self, didFailLoadWithError: error)
}}
```

Then in my ViewController I have this:

```
class NewsViewController: UIViewController, WebViewWithGesturesDelegate {    
@IBOutlet var webView : WebViewWithGestures!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView!.errorDelegate = self
}}
```

However when I run the code I get this:

> 'fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None'

Please help me solve this and learn something new.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Is it a compiler or a runtime error? I got it working (on Xcode 6 beta 5) like this:

Web view:

```
@objc protocol WebViewWithGesturesDelegate {
    optional func webViewWithGestures(webViewWithGestures: WebViewWithGestures!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!)
}

class WebViewWithGestures: UIWebView, UIWebViewDelegate {

    var errorDelegate : WebViewWithGesturesDelegate?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!){
        errorDelegate?.webViewWithGestures!(self, didFailLoadWithError: error)
    }

}
```

View controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WebViewWithGesturesDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView : WebViewWithGestures?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let unwrappedWebView = webView {
            unwrappedWebView.errorDelegate = self
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL.URLWithString("Fail"))
            unwrappedWebView.loadRequest(request)
        } else {
            println("No IBOutlet set")
        }
    }

    func webViewWithGestures(webViewWithGestures: WebViewWithGestures!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("delegateCalled");
    }

}
```

Comment: it's a runtime error. I just ran your code and still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the code. The problem was that the UIWebView was not connected to the ViewController IBOutlet.

Comment: I just updated my answer, you could use WebViewWithGestures? instead of force unwrap the optional to avoid crashes.